# Risks of exceeding current discharge rating of a LiPo battery

Tags: batteries, thermal, lithium-polymer

I have a project that consumes a maximum current of 1.6A, that requires the use of a small LiPo battery. I have one that has the perfect size, but has capacity of 400mA, and a discharge rating of 1C (400mA maximum.) I understand that the internal resistance of a battery is what causes them to heat up under heavy current draw, but would battery thermals be the only risk when drawing 1.6A from a 400mA LiPo battery?

Comment: Terminals? Probably not, but excessive heating internally and you soon have a thermal runaway.

Comment: " a discharge rating of 1C " is your answer.

Comment: Well, you will get high temps, and reduced capacity on every cycle, and reduced cycle life. There could be some hazard.

Comment: Assuming it's capable of 4C the cycle life will be very much reduced if often at 4C and  and somewhat reduced if usually at 2C with some  4C peaks. Others have mentioned thermal issues.

Answer (score 1):

Li-PO batteries made for model airplanes and drones are rated for up to 45C.
Here is a cheap one rated for 25C:

[image]

Comment: AliExpress sells VERY cheap Li-PO batteries with NO C rating.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, or help my use case. My battery needs to be under 40mm x 40mm, and I feel like most LiPos are 2C max

Comment: @jay please include dimension spec in the question and any other relevant information.

Comment: I have never seen a 400mAh Li-PO that is only 40mm x 40mm and with such a weak output current as 2C.